# Classification of industry based on tags

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset (1M entries) on companies where all companies are tagged based on what they do.

For example, Amazon might be tagged with "Retail;E-Commerce;SaaS;Cloud Computing" and Google would have tags like "Search Engine;Advertising;Cloud Computing".

So now I want to analyze a cluster of companies, e.g. all online marketplaces like Amazon, eBay, etsy, and the like. But there is no single tag that I can look for, but I have to use a set of tags to quantify the likelihood for a company to be a marketplace.

For example tags like "Retail", "Shopping", "E-Commerce" are good tags, but then there might be some small consulting agencies or software development firms that consult / build software for online marketplaces and have tags like "consulting;retail;e-commerce" or "software development;e-commerce;e-commerce tools", which I want to exclude as they are not online marketplaces.

I'm wondering what is the best way of identifying all online market places from my dataset. What machine learning algorithm, is suited to select the maximum amount of companies which are in the industry I'm looking for while excluding the ones that are obviously not part of it.

I thought about supervised learning, but I'm not sure because of a few issues:

- Labelling needed, which means I would have to go through thousands of companies and flag them on multiple industries (marketplace, finance, fashion, ...) as I'm interested in 20-30 industries overall
- There are more than 1,000 tags associated with the companies. How would I define my features? 1 feature per tag would lead to a massive dimensionality.

Are there any best practices for such cases?

UPDATE:
It should be possible to assign companies to multiple clusters, e.g. Amazon should be identified as "Marketplace", but also as "Cloud Computing" or "Online Streaming".

I used tf-idf and kmeans to identify tags that form clusters, but I don't know how to assign likelihoods / scores to companies that indicate how good the company fits into the cluster based on its tags.

UPDATE:
While tf-idf in combination with kmeans delivered pretty neat clusters (meaning the companies within a cluster were actually similiar), I also tried to calculate probabilities of belonging to a cluster with Gaussian Mixture Models (GMMs), which led to completely messed up results where companies within a cluster were more or less random or came from a handful different industries.

No idea why this happened though...

UPDATE:
Found the error. I applied a PCA before the GMM to reduce dimensionality, however, this apparently led to the random results. Removing the PCA improved the results significantly.

However, the resulting posterior probabilities of my GMM are 0. or 1. exactly 99.9% of the time. Is there a parameter (I'm using a sklearn [BayesianGMM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html)) that needs to be adjusted to get more valuable probablilities that are a little bit more centered? Because right now everything < 1.0 is not part of a cluster anymore, but there's also few outliers that get a posterior of 1.0 and are thus assigned to an industry. For example, a company with "Baby;Consumer" gets assigned to the "Consumer Electronics" cluster, even though only 1 out of 2 tags may be suggesting this. So I'd like this to get a probability of < 1. such that I can define a threshold based on some cross-validation.

Comment: You could look into clustering techniques, which could form groups of companies based on tag similarity.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I tried initially. While it worked really well to identify clusters of tags that form such industries, I didn't know how to use these clustered tags to identify all companies that belong to it as companies can belong to multiple clusters (see update of my post above). I kind of need a binary classification to identify whether a company belongs to a certain cluster based on the tags.

Comment: Then support vector machines might help.  They are well suited to binary classification.  Clustering analysis could also be valuable, but as you pointed out you need a way of interpreting the clusters.

Comment: @wuser92 What about `Gaussian Mixture Models`? Since the companies such as Amazon can be part of multiple industries you sort of need something with mixed memberships. Which GMM offers. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for you ideas!
@IvanSivak: I just tried this, but for some reason that I don't understand, GMM results are really bad. While k-means actually clustered everything pretty well, meaning all companies within a cluster have simililar tags, GMM clusters (e.g. even the 10 companies with the largest posterior probability for a component) are completely messed up (e.g. telecommunications, health, mobile payments, e-commerce companies ended up being in the top 10).
Any thoughts what might be causing this?

Comment: Got a GMM to work. However, the posteriors are almost always 1. or 0.
I'm using sklearn. Is there something I can adjust?

Comment: GMMs *only* make sense on continuous data. Tags are not Gaussian, ever.

Comment: GMMs *only* make sense on continuous data. Tags are not Gaussian, ever. Not even remotely. Use market basket analysis for tags.